# cakephp - change password method leaves blank the password field in database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i've created a method in my UsersController.php file , so that my users can change their password.
My method php code is:

```
public function changepass() {
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if($this->User->exists()) {         
        $new_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
        $repeat_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newrepeat'];
        if($new_pass == $repeat_pass) {
            $this->User->saveField('password',$new_pass);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Updated successfully'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Passwords did not match'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'changepass'));
        }

    }
}
```

and my changepass.ctp View file is:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create();

    echo $this->Form->input('newpass',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Enter new password'))); 

    echo $this->Form->input('newrepeat',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Confirm new password'))); 
?>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

When i try to browse under the users/changepass,it returns me 2 errors about an undefined index:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 108]

Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 109]
```

pointing at this part of my code:

```
    $new_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
    $repeat_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newrepeat'];
```

and also it (immediately) changes the user password in my database to blank.

I cannot find out what's wrong in any way. I'd be very grateful if you could help me at this point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why `<button type="submit">Save</button>` and not the Form helpers submit button? But what is causing your issue is the missing check on POST! PS: I recommend http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ - a clean approach on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot one vital part about form processing in the controller: Check on POST.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    // only then try to access $this->request->data['User'] content!
}
```

In the case thats it not a post (get), you just display the form - especially without trying to save anything.

Tip: Take a look at baked code (using cake bake) and you will see how it's done properly.

Comment: thank you,this was it! But why is it THAT vital the post check??

Comment: because the action is used for both GET and POST. Without the check and just executing save() either way your action becomes garbage.